# How to randomize rows by value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
player_name skill_point
player1     80
player2     66
player3     42
player4     69
player5     92
player6     31
...          
player12    51
```

I want to make a team generator. My script should randomize the teams based on their skill points every week. The teams should be as equal in skill as possible.

I could order the table by skill points and select every second player, but then team1 will always have an advantage.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: ...but not necessarily equal in size.

Comment: Order by `skill_point` DESC, and pick the top most and bottom most one until you have your desired team size. Rinse and repeat. Picking players from both sides of the "spectrum" will make things more equal.

Comment: What is the team size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127627/mysql-random-sort-than-sort-by-a-specific-column Please look in this link

Comment: Would the saying "You're only as strong as your weakest link" be true in this scenario? One team gets player12 (skill_point 51) and second team gets player11 (skill_point 55), assuming the higher skill_point = the better skill. Would team one be less advantage than team two even if team one had the best player?

Comment: note: summing the skill points to create *equal* teams rarely works.